# Enabling "Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)" in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, labeling

I am using PyQGIS 3.10.

I am working on a project that will display about 30 cities and their forecast weather variables (temperatures, winds, etc.), and some of the labels are a bit close together and technically collide.

I can click this checkbox in the UI, but I haven't been able to find a way to code this in the Python console.

Any ideas?

Below is my code that I've been working with.

```
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
    shadow_settings = QgsTextShadowSettings()
    
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 12))
    text_format.setSize(12)
    text_format.setColor(QColor("white"))
    
    buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
    buffer_settings.setSize(0.5)
    buffer_settings.setColor(QColor("black"))
    
    shadow_settings.setEnabled(True)
    shadow_settings.setOffsetAngle(135)
    shadow_settings.setOffsetDistance(1)
    shadow_settings.setBlurRadius(1.5)
    
    text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
    text_format.setShadow(shadow_settings)
    layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)
    
    layer_settings.fieldName = "City"
    layer_settings.placement = 1
    layer_settings.quadOffset = 7

    layer_settings.enabled = True
    layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Your code is working for me. But you should have "City" attribute for all the layers in the TOC that you are looping through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `displayAll` attributes of `QgsPalLayerSettings` as `True`.

```
layer_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
layer_settings.displayAll = True
```